# How to make SSRS 2005 run fast in general?

Tags: performance-tuning, ssrs

Are there any general rules/tips which we can use to run Sql Server Reporting Services 2005 reports faster?

I have been tuning the Tsql behind the reports but does there exist any SSRS specific performance tuning?

regards

Manjot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS is pretty slow when it comes to generating reports.  The T/SQL tuning is about the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

upgrade to SSRS 2008 or 2008 R2. 
The rendering engine and the startup times are much faster.

That being said,  if part of the issue is with start times, I have heard of people creating warmer scripts to ensure the app pool is constantly running. Caching and saving report  execution may ba an option for you as well. Especially in a batch load DW environment or if the users can stand near current results.

Comment: also check out this linke on rendering performance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353300(SQL.90).aspx#Render

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services Scale-Out Deployment Best Practices:

http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2008/10/21/reporting-services-scale-out-deployment-best-practices.aspx